# While generating table to division unexpected code generated from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

hello i am trying to add table in division when date is shown ...all perform okay ..but in division an unwanted code generate like [object Object],[object Object]...i want to remove that code.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var now = new Date();
            var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
            var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var today = now.getFullYear() + "-" + (month) + "-" + (day);
            $('#DT').val(today);
   $.fn.ABC = function () {
                var selectedValue = $("#DT").val();
                alert(selectedValue);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("DateWiseData", "ProcessWaxAss")',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'SelectedDate': selectedValue }),
                    success: function (waxAsslist) {
                        if (Object.keys(waxAsslist).length > 0) {
                            $('#detailtbl').text("");
                            $('#detailtbl').append('<div class="card">' +
                                '<div class="card-header card-header-primary card-header-icon">' +
                                '<div class="card-icon"><i class="material-icons">assignment</i>' +
                                '</div><h4 class="card-title">Wax Assembly List</h4></div>' +
                                '<div class="card-body">' +
                                '<div class="material-datatables">' +
                                '<table id="datatables" class="table table-striped table-no-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%">' +
                                '<thead>' +
                                '<tr>' +
                                '<th><b>PRC No</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Die No</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Description</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Metal</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Qty</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Reject Qty</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Shell</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>Total Weight</b></th>' +
                                '<th><b>User</b></th>' +
                                '</tr>' +
                                '</thead>' +
                                '<tbody>' +
                             $.each(waxAsslist, function (i, data) {
                                 setTimeout(function () {
                                     $('#datatables tbody').append(
                                         '<tr>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.PRCNO + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.MOULDCODE + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.DESCRIPTION + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.METALNAME + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.Qty + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.RejectQty + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.Shell + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.TotalWt + '</td>'
                                     + '<td>' + data.USERNAME + '</td>'
                                     + '</tr>'
                                 )
                                 }, 1000);
                             }),
                                '</tbody>' +
                                '</table>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '</div>');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () { alert('Error. Please try again.'); }
                });
            };
            $.fn.ABC();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
<input type="date" id="DT">
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="detailtbl">
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my controller where from my data came.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DateWiseData(DateTime SelectedDate)
    {
        var Dw = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        var idparam = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "date",
            Value = SelectedDate
        };
        var waxAsslist = Db.Database.SqlQuery<spDataWaxAss>("exec sp_PRCWax_Assembly_Get_Date @date", idparam).ToList();
        return Json(waxAsslist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

return json value like this
[json return value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFyWc.png)

in output it will be show like this ...
[output generate like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvxSh.png)
i want to remove yellow highlighted portion ...i don't know from where it generate...
can any one help me..

Comment: The problem is because you're appending the result of `$.each()` to the HTML string you're building, not the HTML within that function.

Comment: can you explain me more.? how to resolve this problem.?

Comment: Move the `$.each()` call outside of the `append()`. That being said it's really not good practice to have this much HTML within your JS code. I'd strongly suggest you look in to using a templating library.

Comment: okay thank you...for help. i do excellently what you say and  its working..thank you again

Comment: and one more problem is there when generate table.....data table not generate with pagination ...